# Search for equally different numbers in array

Tags: javascript

Im making Tic Tac Toe game and i have a problem. I noticed that winnable situation is when there are 3 numbers which are equally different (for example, "0,1,2"(1-0=1, 2-1=1) or "0,4,8"(4-0=4, 8-4=4) or "1,4,7"(4-1=3, 7-4=3), if i start counting from "0"). Numbers are boxes' coordinates from 0 to 8.

Have no idea how to check if there are numbers like that.

```
//html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>


//js
const BOXES = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
let turn = true;
let opened = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
let x = [];
let o = [];

for (let i = 0; i < BOXES.length; i++) {
    BOXES[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (turn == true && opened[i] == 1) {
            BOXES[i].innerHTML = "<p>X</p>";
            x.push(i);
            x.sort();
        }
        if (turn == false && opened[i] == 1) {
            BOXES[i].innerHTML = "<p>O</p>";
            o.push(i);
            o.sort();
        }
        opened[i] = 0;
        turn = !turn
    })
}
```

I'm going to paste every x coordinates to array "x" (x.push[i]) and paste o coordinates to "o" array (o.push[i]) but i have no idea how to searc for equally different numbers in arrays.

Comment: @JohnColeman, i mean  n, n + y, n + 2y

Comment: It might be a better design to represent your board as a 3x3 2-dimensional array rather than a 1 dimensional array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create two functions, one to generate an array of "differences", and one to check if all those numbers are the same. See code below:

```
const array = [1, 4, 7];

// Function to get differences
function getDiffs(array) {
  let diffs = [];
  for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if(i > 0) {
      diffs.push(array[i] - array[i-1]);
    }
  }
  return diffs;
}

// Function to compare those numbers to see if they are the same
function checkSameValue(diffs) {
  let item = diffs[0];
  for(let i=0; i< diffs.length; i++) {
    if(diffs[i] !== item) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work.

```
function didWin(arr) {
    let len = arr.length; // I like checking length once because it's O(n). Probably won't matter for your game, though.
    if (len < 3)
      return false; // No win if less than 3 moves
    var firstDiff = arr[1] - arr[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < len - 1; ++i) { // We don't check the first (already done) or the last (no arr[len] element)
        if (arr[i+1] - arr[i] != firstDiff)
            return false; // We know we are done as soon as the difference is not equal
    }
    return true; // We have now checked that all differences are equal
}
```

Comment: this function looks for differences equal to the first one?

Comment: It returns true if there are at least three items and the difference between each subsequent item is the same.